# Is it okay to add information without asking a question?

Tags: discussion, questions, self-answer

Can you add information without asking a question? For example, I found a Firefox addon that lets you see the generated source of a page, but I don't want to add it to an answered question. Can I just start a "question" to get this information out there?

Comment: Go ahead and ask a new question.  And, then answer it with your answer.

Comment: @jinguy - Did you just answer a question about asking questions by posting a comment?

Comment: make it an answer @jinguy and i will accept

Comment: @Jon B: Did you call him @jinguy just to throw the poor newbie off?

Comment: Damnit, @jjnguy - why does your name look like "jinguy".

Comment: @Jon, I get that quite often actually.  Sometimes I decide to change my name to Justin, but people will still refer to me as jjnguy, so that doesn't help.

Comment: @Mic, who are you calling a newbie?!?!

Comment: @jjnguy, he's probably calling ellisgeek a newbie.

Comment: @Pop, I hope so, otherwise there will be blood!

Comment: @jjnguy: Not mine, I hope. That would be highly distasteful.

Comment: @mic, I would never threaten a mod...(Not even a newbie one)

Comment: Doesn't right click -> view source do the same thing without your addon?

Comment: [It's OK to Ask and Answer Your Own Questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go ahead and ask a new question. And, then answer it with your answer.